# Get raster pixel value within a shapefile polygon

Tags: python, raster, gdal, geopandas

I have the below GeoPandas dataframe that has:

1. two columns: geometry and raster_val
2. 13 rows

The first row is shown below.

```
    geometry                                                  raster_val
0   POLYGON ((746124.59744 3382358.69579, 746124.5...         5.0
```

I want to use the Geopandas geometry to get the raster pixels inside each polygon and store the pixel values in separate numpy arrays.

Comment: raster_val is a numerical value that represents the class of each polygon. There are 6 different class types. I want to use the geometry to clip a raster file.